# How to use the Larave DB Facade to get the first record with a date close to a particular date

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, orm

I am trying to get the first transaction that was recorded close to a particular date using the Laravel 8 DB Facade.

I have tried to use it in the following manner

```
       $lastest_transaction = DB::table($targetTable)
        ->where('date', '<=', date('F'))
        ->where('id', '=', $client->id)
        ->where('branch', '=', session('branch'))
        ->get();
```

but it's not giving me the correct transaction.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the record closest to the date, you can sort by the date in descending order, which would make the first record the "largest" date that's less than or equal to what you are searching for:

```php
$lastest_transaction = DB::table($targetTable)
        ->where('date', '<=', date('F'))
        ->where('id', '=', $client->id)
        ->where('branch', '=', session('branch'))
        ->orderBy('date', 'DESC') // Order by the date in descending order
        ->first(); // Get the first record
```